# How do I change the spell check language independently from the hardware keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard, languages, external-keyboard, spell-check, asus-transformer-infinity

I'm using an **Asus Transformer Pad Infinity** with a German (Swiss variant) hardware keyboard and with the standard Asus variant of Android version 4.2.1.

On a regular basis I need to type in **both German and English**, so it would be nice to have spell checking in both languages. However, whenever I switch to English spell checking, then the tablet assumes I'm using an English keyboard layout and swaps keys around such as the <kbd>Y</kbd> and <kbd>Z</kbd> keys. Is there any way around this?

Comment: What a great question!